# How can i share Java project on ftp server using Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, ftp, shared-hosting, remote-server

I have an FTP host and I want to upload a Java project to a remote server using NetBeans, but it doesn't give the remote server option with Java projects - it works with PHP but not Java.

Is there any resource available that could help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This NetBeans plugin might help you http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/39197/ftpsitedeployer ,this was designed  particularly  for upload changes to a Java (jsp,class files) or PHP website